# How can I create a new folder in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

How can I create a new folder in asp.net using c#?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`path` is the variable holding the directory name

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 39):

```
var folder = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/random");
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, you **need** to use `Server.MapPath`.

Answer (score 8):

[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). However you will have to make sure the application pool user has rights to create the directory.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Path)) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
}
```

try this, for a better one.

Answer (score 5):

First, remember that the directory will appear on the server, not the client. You also have to have the rights to create the folder. Finally, in a load balanced environment the folder will appear only on the server that created it, it won't be replicated unless there is some background service that does that for you.

```
using System.IO;

Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(folderPath));
```

There is no need to check if folder exists, because  [if it exists method CreateDirectory does nothing.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

Comment: That was the point i am looking for. What if the folder already exists. Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 3):

Most people will say `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` so I'll provide an alternative:

[`DirectoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8dtw1d6.aspx)

The DirectoryInfo object will give you access to a decent amount of information about the parent directory in case there are conditions for creating the subdirectory (like checking if the parent actually exists or not). Perhaps something like:

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Path\\To\\Parent\\");

if(directoryInfo.Exists)
{
    directoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory("NewFolder");
}
```